# Highcharts do not render

Tags: symfony, highcharts

I'm trying to use a ObHighcharts bundle with symfony2.

Basically, it generates the following code:

```
 $(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {"renderTo":"dailyChart","type":"spline"},
series: {"name":"My spline","data":
[
    [1369519200,"2055.5"],
    [1370469600,"1986.3"],
    [1369087200,"1804.0"],
    [1368655200,"1783.3"],
    [1366840800,"1734.3"],
    [1369000800,"1693.2"],
    [1368309600,"1515.4"],
*lots of other similar data*
]
}, 
title: {"text":"My Chart"},
xAxis: {"title":{"type":"datetime","title":"Date"}},
yAxis: {"title":{"title":"Sugar, mg","min":0}}
});
});
```

But when I try rendering it, there's just a title, an export button and a blank screen. Console shows no signs of errors. What can be wrong here? Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data element is a string:

```
[
    [1369519200,"2055.5"],
    [1370469600,"1986.3"],
    [1369087200,"1804.0"],
    [1368655200,"1783.3"],
    [1366840800,"1734.3"],
    [1369000800,"1693.2"],
    [1368309600,"1515.4"],
*lots of other similar data*
]
```

It should be something like `[1369519200,2055.5]`.
You also need to enclose the series element in brackets:

```
series: [{"name":"My spline","data":
[
    [1369519200,"2055.5"],
    [1370469600,"1986.3"],
    [1369087200,"1804.0"],
    [1368655200,"1783.3"],
    [1366840800,"1734.3"],
    [1369000800,"1693.2"],
    [1368309600,"1515.4"],
]}
]
```

Also, note that your time elements are not in ascending order. For a proper datetime axis you need to go in ascending time.

Comment: No, it's completely clean. Weird :(

Comment: Thanks! It worked. One question though - how do I properly format the date? It doesn't seem to get the UTC timestamp and I can't really do a native highcharts formatting from the server. Or can I?

Comment: Depends on how your data is returned. You could use `[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), yVal]`. See here about that function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61370/discussion-between-nainy-and-wergeld).